# Ubuntu 13.10: I still hear sound from laptop speakers when headphones connected

Tags: sound, 13.10, headphones, speakers

When I connect headphones to laptop with 13.10 I hear sound from speakers and from headphones at same time. How to fix this? 64bit, lenovo y570

Answer (score 1):

It may not change the settings automatically.

Try going to "Sound Settings" -> "Output" and choose the device you want to output to. It solved my problem with an HP USB headphones.

Answer (score 1):

Probably, your Headphone Jack Sense is turned off..

Try this:

- Open Terminal.
- Type in `alsamixer`.
- Locate and navigate to "Headphone".
- Press `m`.

This should turn on your Headphone Jack Sense.